# How to declare variables inside sed

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have the following input file:

```
This is just junk
stuff this should not
appear in the output
module instance1 (
.a  (x),
.b  (y),
.c  (z)
);
Module instance2 (
.a  (x),
.b  (y),
.c  (z)
);
So is this part of the
file so no output here
as well`<br>
I want the following output:<br>
`module instance1 ( 
.a (x),
.b (y),
.c (z)
);
Module instance2 (
.a  (x),
.b  (y),
.c  (z)
);
```

I tried running the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
block=`sed -n '/($/p' test1
echo $block
for bloc in "$block"; do 
sed -n "/$bloc/,/);/{p}" test1
done
```

But I am getting the following error:
`sed: -e expression #1, char 19: unterminated address regex`
But why isn't the above script working?
**Edit**: The test1 is the input file shown above

Comment: Your `sed` command is not closed. In **block=`sed -n '/($/p' test1**, closing (`) is missing.

Comment: There I am searching for a line ending with (

Comment: `for bloc in "$block"` can only ever loop once as `"$block"` is a single string.

Comment: Looks like you left the back tick off the end of your "block=`sed -n '/($/p' test1" expression. What exactly do you want this script to do?

Answer (score 2):

When the shell expands `$bloc` inside the sed script it ends up with:

```
sed -n "/module instance1 (
Module instance2 (
Module instance2 (/,/);/{p}" test1
```

Which, as you might imagine, it isn't too happy about.

If you want `sed` to print out only the lines between `module .... (` and `);` then just do that directly instead of playing this game

```
sed -n '/^[mM]odule .* ($/,/);/p'
```

If you need them in separate files or something then you need to fix up how you are finding the module names and looping over the starting lines

Comment: I need to use variables in sed because I want to make a generalized script not specifically for this example file. Could you please tell me how to do it with the variable

Comment: Using variables in your `sed` script isn't the problem but the contents of those variables might be. They can't contain anything that wouldn't be legal if you typed it out in that part of the `sed` script (since that's all the shell is doing). So you get to use a delimiter that won't clash and you get to escape the variable contents for anything that might cause other problems.

Comment: for loop will assign different values in $block to $bloc which are delimited by space. Can we change this delimiter to newline??

Comment: Not in a `for` loop, no. You can with a `while read` loop though. See [Don't Read Lines With For](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor) for details.

Answer (score -1):

```
sed -n "/${bloc:-^}/,/);/ {p;}" test1
```

- add a `;` in action block (or add a new line if you prefer)
- return `^` if bloc is null or empty. This avoid a `//` pattern

Test

```
bloc='Module instance2 ('
sed -n "/${bloc:-^}/,/);/ {p;}" YourFile

Module instance2 (
.a  (x),
.b  (y),
.c  (z)
);
Module instance2 (
.a  (x),
.b  (y),
.c  (z)
);
```

Comment: why -1 ? any explaination